# Deleting from a C Linked List (Pointer to pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I found the following code fragment in C language which deletes an element from the list

```
void
remove_ll(struct link_list **head, int key)
{
        struct link_list **cur;
        for(cur = head; *cur; ) {
                struct link_list *entry = *cur;
                if (entry->key == key) {
                        *cur = entry->next;
                        free(entry);
                } else {
                        cur = &entry->next;
                }
        }
}
```

I am trying to understand how it works.

This is my idea.

```
List example:

     0x1f7d018               0x1f7d038              0x1f7d078
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++
|0x2174010:       |     |0x1f7d070:       |     |0x1f7d090:       |
|key = 10         |     |key = 34         |     |key = 90         |
|&next = 0x1f7d038|++++>|&next = 0x1f7d078|++++>|&next = NULL     |
|                 |     |                 |     |                 |
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++

After deleting the value 34

     0x1f7d018               0x1f7d038
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++
|0x2174010:       |     |0x1f7d090:       |
|key = 10         |     |key = 90         |
|&next = 0x1f7d038|++++>|&next = NULL     |
|                 |     |                 |
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++
```

This is correct?

*Best regards.*

Comment: Run it and see.

Comment: I've seen some horrible brace style, but this one takes the cake.

Answer (score 1):

It is more precise like so:

```
List example:

     0x1f7d018               0x1f7d038              0x1f7d078
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++
|0x2174010:       |     |0x1f7d070:       |     |0x1f7d090:       |
|key = 10         |     |key = 34         |     |key = 90         |
|&next = 0x1f7d038|++++>|&next = 0x1f7d078|++++>|&next = NULL     |
|                 |     |                 |     |                 |
+++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++     +++++++++++++++++++

After deleting the value 34

     0x1f7d018                                      0x1f7d078
+++++++++++++++++++                             +++++++++++++++++++
|0x2174010:       |                             |0x1f7d090:       |
|key = 10         |                             |key = 90         |
|&next = 0x1f7d078|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>|&next = NULL     |
|                 |                             |                 |
+++++++++++++++++++                             +++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Why in the example &next = 0x1f7d078 after deleting the value 34?

Comment: To truly delete a node in a linked list, you should set the previous node's next to point to the next node.  Then you can safely delete the target node.  With linked lists, especially home-brew link lists, you always have to look out for memory leaks.

Comment: [link]https://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions

In the section "favorite hack"

Answer (score 1):

When you are deleting any node from a linked list then you are actually freeing up the memory allocated by that node.

So in order to maintain your linked list you need to take care that the Node1 which is previous to the Node2 (which is going to be deleted) should point directly to the Node3 which is next to the Node2.

Node1 --> Node2 --> Node 3

Suppose, we are deleting Node2

So the next pointer of Node1 should point to the address of Node3. And remember to free the memory allocated by Node2 for avoiding memory leaks.

In case of doubly linked list, you need to take care next as well as prev pointer. You can try implementing doubly linked list. It will sure help you to understand better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pay more attention to the value of &next